# @font-face doesn't load the font at all

Tags: html, css

This is not really a question but a **kind reminder** to all newbies like me.

I literally spent a couple of hours trying to fix a *@font-face* I was trying to load into my website.

This was the code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font Name One';
    src: url('fonts/font-name-one.woff') format('woff');
    etc, more links;}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Name Two';
    src: url('font-name-two.woff') format('woff');
    etc, more links;}
```

One was loading correctly, the other one was not. I wondered if it could be a problem with the font, with the files, with some comma or other syntax mistakes, etc. Nothing seemed to work. **And then...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized it was simply that the *second* font being imported did not link to **inside** the *fonts* folder.

So I changed it:

`src: url('fonts/font-name-two.woff') format('woff');`

And voilà, simple as that.